# Does it consider bad if a react component without any state is defined and rendered inside another react component?

Tags: reactjs, nested

I know that we shouldn't define and render a react component inside another react component because it's going to mess up the states of those components.

But for the example below, I'm wondering if there are any potential issues.

```
export default function Post() {
  const { number } = useParams();

  const headerQuery = useHeader(number);
  const bodyQuery = useBody(number);

  const Header = () => {
    if (headerQuery.isLoading) {
      return <p>Loading...</p>;
    }
    
    // Assume that headerQuery.data here is just a simple string
    return <div>{headerQuery.data}</div>;
  };

  const Body = () => {
    if (bodyQuery.isLoading) {
      return <p>Loading...</p>;
    }

    return <div>{bodyQuery.data}</div>
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {Header()}
      {Body()}
      {/* or
       <Header />
       <Body />
       */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Because those `Header` and `Body` components don't have any states so I think it's the same as below:

```
export default function Post() {
  const { number } = useParams();

  const headerQuery = useHeader(number);
  const bodyQuery = useBody(number);

  const header = headerQuery.isLoading ? <p>Loading...</p> : <div>{headerQuery.data}</div>

  const body = bodyQuery.isLoading ? <p>Loading...</p> : <div>{bodyQuery.dat}</div>

  return (
    <div>
      {header}
      {body}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The reason I want to define `header` and `body` as components as in the first code snippet is because I don't want to use more than one ternary operator if I have to handle more than the loading state (`isLoading ? isSomething ? <h1>...<h1> : <h2>...<h2> : <div>...<div>`).

I can absolutely move `header` and `body` out of `post` but if they're nested inside `post`, are there any issues?

Comment: As long as they will never have state, using components is OK. If you ever add state, you will end up with a render/re-render fiasco (probably).

Comment: Alternatively, maybe better, would be to do the conditional logic outside the `return` by setting variables to the preferred output. Then, just put the output variable into the `return`

Comment: I'd do neither; I'd externalize the components.

Comment: It's not pretty, but wouldn't cause any problems. I'd consider having them in `useMemo()` though.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly OK to have react components that contain other react components. The contained components will only re-render if they rely on state that has changed, and even if they do re-render - that just updates he virtual dom which isn't free but is pretty light weight.

Each component can have its own state. That is OK and how things work. What you cannot do is introduce "conditional state" into a component. i.e. all your useXXXXX code should be at the top of your component and not inside a function you call or within an if statement, etc.

You absolutely want to use components, e.g. `<Header />` and not `{Header()`).

I recommend [watching this video](https://youtu.be/QuLfCUh-iwI) to learn about the differences between `<Component />` and `{Component()}`.